# How to create a custom attribute in ApacheDS?

Tags: ldap, custom-attributes, apacheds

I am trying to create a custom attribute in ApacheDS, I have followed an existing attribute and created a new one named 'passwordUpdateTime':

[image]

But when I wanted to add it into my person object, I couldn't find in the list:

[image]

If I am forcing to add the attribute, ApacheDS is stopping me to do so:

[image]

Has anyone met the same problem before?

Thanks,
Leo

Comment: you should add the new attribute to the "may" of your object class which the object you want to has the new attribute. and do not listen the warning, do not consider that it does not seem in auto complete. force add and force enter value for it.

Answer (score 0):

in case of the Apache DS running stand alone you need to restart the server to make the atrribute visible (at least until milestone M-17) Apache DS scheme is NOT dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

### **The solution worked for me.**

### 1. Export any existing attribute as .ldif file from the schema of inetOrgPerson using ApacheDS

[image]

### 2. Open the exported attribute .ldif file in ApacheDS and edit the attribute according to your needs and Run the file

[image]

### 3. After running the file verify that your new created attribute is listed under "ou=attributeTypes,cn=inetorgperson,ou=schema"

[image]

### 4. Now export the inetOrgPerson objectClass as .ldif file, listed under "ou=objectClasses,cn=inetorgperson,ou=schema"

[image]

### 5. After exporting, verify that inetOrgPerson objectClass is exported successfully. After verifying, delete the inetOrgPerson objectClass from the location "ou=objectClasses,cn=inetorgperson,ou=schema"

[image]

### 6. Now open the exported .ldif file containing inetOrgPerson objectClass from the exported location. Put the names of your custom attributes and Run the file

[image]

### 7. Now you'll be able to use your custom added attributes. Add new entry, and must reload schema.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

### Boom

[image]